# Getting access to resources from an ArrayAdapter in Android

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I have some resources defined, e.g.:

```
<color name="lightGrey">#FFCCCCCC</color>
<integer name="KEY_POSITION_ARM">2</integer>
```

...and I have an ArrayAdapter displaying items to TextViews.  I'm trying to access the values with code like:

```
keyPosition = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.KEY_POSITION_ARM);
moduleDataView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.darkgreen));
```

...but I get errors like "The method getResources() is undefined for the type ContinuityAdapter".  (ContinuityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter)

Is there a good way around this?

Thanks

This is an example:

```
switch (currentModule.keyPosition) {
case activity.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.KEY_POSITION_ARM):
    moduleDataView.keyPosition.setText("TEST");
    moduleDataView.keyPosition.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    break;
case R.integer.KEY_POSITION_ARM:
    moduleDataView.keyPosition.setText("ARM");
    moduleDataView.keyPosition.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    break;
}
```

The first case give an error, and the second doesn't but doesn't use the value from the XML file either.  Although as you say I can just use the R... value as long as I use it that way everywhere.  Just not sure if this is considered 'best practice'.  Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) object to call [Context.getResources()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29) method. Usually you can pass a Context or its subclass (i.e. Activity) through the constructor of your custom adapter.

Like:

```
public ContinuityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private final Context mContext;
    ...
    public ContinuityAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }
}
```

and then use:

```
mContext.getResources()...
```

**Edit**:
This seem to be the case to avoid switch. See:

- [Ways to eliminate switch in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126409/ways-to-eliminate-switch-in-code)
- [Alternative to Switch Case in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425659/alternative-to-switch-case-in-java)
- [How to avoid long switch-case statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666846/how-to-avoid-long-switch-case-statements)

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried it and I thought it didn't work, but now I realize that I was getting another error doing: 'switch (foo) {
case activity.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.KEY_POSITION_ARM):'  The case statement obviously requires a constant expression, even though the resource is constant.  Am I stuck using if statements?

Comment: I need to see more code. Generally I tried to avoid switch cases or I use the resource id directly (i.e. case R.id.xyz).

Comment: I edited the question to include a better code example. Thanks